# How to start with integrating utility accounts into app?

Tags: api, new-operator, utility

I am starting to develop an app with a friend of mine and at its core it needs to sync accounts and data from utility providers (think energy, wifi, etc.). How do we start with that? Do we need to reach out to the utility providers to access their API's? Where should we start?

I am not a programmer, I want to know who I need to reach out to in order to support my partner.

I can clarify anything if necessary, thank you!

Comment: This is off-topic on stackoverflow (a site for programmers) and is n not even a technical question but perhaps one for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ; BTW, your question is related to https://gdpr-info.eu/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question. It is not appropiate for migration to other [se] sites, because it is not in any way specific or clear.